# How to broadcast transaction using litecoire-lib?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin, litecoin

How to broadcast transactions using litecore-lib for nodejs? Is there any public endpoint to push the tx once signed? Public endpoint for testnet?

Answer (score 0):

- Guide to create a transaction with [littecore-lib](https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecore-lib/blob/master/docs/examples.md#create-a-transaction), then use `toString` to generate raw transaction data.
- Broadcast it at [here](https://tltc.bitaps.com/broadcast)